# Crystal report printing wrong chart from application

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I have a Crystal Report where I am generating an Numeric axis line chart.In the Data tab of the chart expert I have selected a datetime field with the option "For Each Record" and in the Show value field I have selected a varchar field.That means in the x-axis the datetime field will be plotted.In the y-axis the varchar field will be plotted.I have made the varchar field in the report as the Number type.I have made the datetime field as date type.
In the Crystal report preview the report is showing correct plot with the correct data.

Now I have deployed the report in my java application.I am using Crystal report Java api to generate the report in PDf format from my application.In the generated PDf from my application the plot is getting messed up.The y-axis(varchar) is coming up fine.But the x-axis is showing some random data.As a result the report plot is wrong.

I am using Crystal report 11.8.8 version api to print the report.My application is an standalone desktop application using java 5 and Jboss application server.

Please help.